# How to show that $\mathrm{Gal}(\Bbb Q(\xi_{p^n})/\Bbb Q(\xi_{p^m}))$ is cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, cyclotomic-fields

How to show that $G=\mathrm{Gal}[\Bbb Q(\xi_{p^n})/\Bbb Q(\xi_{p^m})]$ cyclic?
Here $p \not = 2$ is a prime number and $n>m>0$ are natural numbers.
$\xi_{p^n}$ and $\xi_{p^m}$ are cyclotomic roots.

I know that the order of $ G $ is $|G|=p^{n-m}$

How I found $a \in G$ such that $a^{p^{n-m}}=1$ and how generally I found such $a$ in other cyclic cases?

Comment: why G is subgroup of $Gal(\Bbb Q(\xi_{p^n})/\Bbb Q)$?
and I would like to know how to deal with the statement when $p=2$ and $m>1$

Comment: If $\sigma \in G$, then $\sigma$ is an automorphism of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^n})$ fixing $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^m})$. In particular, it also fix $\Bbb Q$. Therefore, $\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^n}) / \Bbb Q)$ (the latter being a Galois extension).

Comment: @Watson yes indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group $G$ is a subgroup of $\mathrm{Gal}(\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^n}) / \Bbb Q)$, which is isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z/p^n \Bbb Z)^{\times}$ (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725821) related question). 
This is a cyclic group when $p>2$ is prime. Since any subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic, we are done.

Comment: For $p=2$, the question has been addressed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2827464).