# How to show that $G=\mathrm{Gal}[\Bbb Q(\xi_{2^n})/\Bbb Q(\xi_{2^m})]$ cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

How to show that $G=\mathrm{Gal}[\Bbb Q(\xi_{2^n})/\Bbb Q(\xi_{2^m})]$ cyclic?
 $n>m>1$ are natural numbers.
$\xi_{2^n}$ and $\xi_{2^m}$ are cyclotomic roots.

I know that the order of $ G $ is $|G|=2^{n-m}$

Comment: The only thing I succeed at it is to show that 
$G \cong Z_2 \times Z_{2^{n-2}}/Z_2 \times  Z_{2^{m-2}}$ but why this is cyclic?

Comment: The Galois groups are generated by the automorphisms $\xi \mapsto \xi^{-1}$ and $\xi \mapsto \xi^{5}$.