# Order and Structure of Galois group

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

I'm struggling with a question I've got as I can't seem to wrap my head around Galois theory much.

i)Prove that $\zeta^{2}$ is a primitive 8th root of unity and $\zeta^{4}$ is a primitive 4th root of unity. Deduce then that $\zeta$ is a constructible number, where $\zeta$ is primitive 16th root of unity

For this one I'm unsure again, since the only question I've done like it, is when showing that $-\zeta$ is the primitive 5th root of unity when $\zeta$ is the primitive 10th root of unity but I'm  confused on how I'm meant to apply that knowledge here.

ii) Find the order and structure of the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q}$, where $\zeta$ is the primitive 16th root of unity in $\mathbb{C}$.

I found this [Structure of $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{15})/\mathbb{Q})$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725821/structure-of-gal-mathbbq-zeta-15-mathbbq) which I think may be what I'm looking for in terms of helping my understanding and applying it to $\zeta_{16}$ but I'm unsure.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $15$ and $16$ are very different numbers; say, $16$ is a power of $2$ while $15$ isn't.

Comment: This is just about the splitting fields of cyclotomic polynomials

Comment: Have you covered a result stating that the square root of a constructible number is constructible?

Comment: For ii), the answer in your linked question should give you everything you need.

Comment: For i), you just have to show that $\zeta^2$ has order $8$ and $\zeta^4$ has order $4$, given that $\zeta$ has order $16$. You can forget what $\zeta$ otherwise means in this part. Nothing complicated here, just first semester group theory. And then use what Jyrki Lahtonen said.

Comment: Instead of thinking about it as square roots, you can think about angle bisectors to construct $\zeta^16$.