# Determining structure of Galois Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I have to determine the structure of the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q}$, where $\zeta$ is the primitive 16th root of unity. I have found an example of a question like this before where they determined that when $\zeta$ was the primitive 10th root of unity then the structure of the Galois group was simply isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z})^{\times}= \{1,3,7,9\}$.

My question is then, can I do something similar here? Say its isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/16\mathbb{Z})$ which I think is equal to {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15}? If so, should I also know the generator and order of this group?

Am I on the right path or just making up math? Should I be basing it off [Structure of $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{15})/\mathbb{Q})$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725821) instead? Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: You should be able to follow the reasoning of the earlier problem and adapt it to your problem.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm unsure what you mean by that. Are you saying then that my thinking of the group structure being $(\mathbb{Z}/16\mathbb{Z})$ is on the right track or that its not and I should follow the earlier problem more?

Comment: If you're stuck on $n=16$ then you should start with easier cases. Have you done $n=2$? $n=4$? $n=8$?

Comment: Powers of two (here sixteen) behave a bit differently from the rest of them if you want to , for example, write the group as a direct product. But, yeah, the general recipe of $(\Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z})^\times$ works. In general the proof is not totally obvious, so do work out these small case like ancient mathematician suggested.

Comment: I'm not saying it's right, and I'm not saying it's wrong. I'm saying that if you understand how the other solution was found, you should be able to make whatever adjustments are necessary to solve your question.